# Add multiple values to a meta field

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a script in PHP,
through which I can add the values of post id in database (using wordpress as my CMS).

This is my code:

```
$postid = $_POST['post_id'];
$users_ids = $_POST['user_id'];
$metavalueuser = $postid;
$single = true;


$newvalue = $postid;
$oldvalue = get_user_meta( $users_ids, 'post_likes', true );
$arrvalue = array($oldvalue,$newvalue);
update_user_meta($users_ids, 'post_likes', $arrvalue);
```

The problem with the code is that it doesn't add multiple values.

Whenever a new value is added, the older value is erased.

I need to add all the value with comma.

So that I can call them using foreach function.

Comment: Don't really get what you need?

Comment: For example
Value1 = 5
So meta key is set to value5
Now again function is called

value2 = 7
so meta is set to 7

Instead 
i want meta to set to 5,7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$postid = $_POST['post_id'];
    $users_ids = $_POST['user_id'];
    $metavalueuser = $postid;
    $single = true;


    $newvalue = $postid;
    $oldvalue = get_user_meta( $users_ids, 'post_likes', true );
    $arrvalue =  $oldvalue.', '.$newvalue; // store as a comma seperated string
    update_user_meta($users_ids, 'post_likes', $arrvalue);`enter code here`
```

Now after retriving value from post meta you can convert it into array by using [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)